Hash calculation for TLS 1.2 Finished message
I'm trying to understand the data that go into a TLS "Finished" handshake message. At present I'm focused on TLS 1.2 -- if I can't get that right then there's no point in looking at other versions. I've followed RFC 5246, but the RFC contains some ambiguities. My resolution of the ambiguities might be why I'm calculating the wrong answer.
The data are produced by the PRF. I'm confident I have the PRF and the master_secret right, because it's producing other things (keys, etc.) that are correct. So the problem must be with the hash input to the PRF. For that, I'm making the following assumptions.

The hash function for this purpose is sha256 (for all ciphersuites covered by RFC 5246). The RFC seems to imply that it should be hmac-sha256, but I don't find that plausible because HMAC requires a key that we don't have.
The hash inputs include handshake messages in both directions, not just one direction. That''s unclear in section 7.4.9, but seems to be implied by section 7.4.8.
All handshake messages except HelloRequest and Finished are included in the calculation. (There is a complication related to the second Finished message, but that's a separate issue.) Non-handshake messages like ChangeCipherSpec are not included.
The data hashed are all of the "Fragment" part, starting with the handshake type (one byte) and the three-byte length. We process the PlainText form, not the encrypted form, so the MAC and padding are not included.

Where has my reasoning gone wrong?

Actually, the details for TLS 1.3 are completely different from TLS 1.2.  It might be easier to go directly to TLS 1.3

Interesting idea, but for now I'm reluctant to lose my large investment in getting 1.2 right. I'll keep it in mind as a backup solution.


The hash function for this purpose is sha256 (for all ciphersuites covered by RFC 5246). The RFC seems to imply that it should be hmac-sha256, but I don't find that plausible because HMAC requires a key that we don't have.

Quotation of the RCFC; "For the PRF defined in Section 5, the Hash MUST be the Hash used as the basis for the PRF.", so not the PRF itself. It also means that just assuming SHA-256 is wrong for cipher suites that do not end with SHA-256.

The hash inputs include handshake messages in both directions, not just one direction. That''s unclear in section 7.4.9, but seems to be implied by section 7.4.8.

I think that is implied with all, and the fact that the client includes one more message in the calculation: the finished message send by the server.

There is a complication related to the second Finished message, but that's a separate issue.

Is it a separate issue? Maybe for the server but definitely not for the client.

The data hashed are all of the "Fragment" part, starting with the handshake type (one byte) and the three-byte length. We process the PlainText form, not the encrypted form, so the MAC and padding are not included.

Obviously the encryption should have taken place yet either, but I guess that is implied by your description.

Other than #1 I don't see how your description is wrong, but that doesn't mean that the implementation is without fault.
I strongly suggest you to use the hints in this Q/A to make sure that your implementation is correct.



There is a complication related to the second Finished message, but that's a separate issue.



Is it a separate issue? Maybe for the server but definitely not for the client. At present I'm trying to debug the first Finished message.



I strongly suggest you to use the hints in this Q/A to make sure that your implementation is correct.
I noticed one bug there, in the claim that the sequence number was 3 for a Finished message. In fact it's zero, the sequence number is reset by a ChangeCipherSpec. Apart from that, I'm in agreement with everything. (And I've done things like checking my implementation of HMAC against test vectors.) So it must be down to an obscure coding bug. Back to desk checking.


PS I'm obviously not quoting text properly. How should I do it?

Won't work in comments, I think. Possibly best to use italics instead using markdown. By the way, there should be a few complete walkthroughs on the internet including hexadecimal message formats and whatnot. Those should work as long as you manage to use the exact same values (which can be tricky due to the use of RNG's of course).

Problem solved. It was a silly parameter-passing error, meaning that I used "client finished" instead of "server finished", and vice versa, in a PRF call. My original assumptions for the hash calculation were correct.
One other detail I had to work out by trial and error: the ChangeCipherSpec message changes the cipher for only one direction, not both. In hindsight the RFC does imply this, but it wasn't obvious.
